# find where my message forwarded in telegram using python?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

Is there a way to find where my message forwarded in telegram using **Telegram libraries in python** ?

note : my channels messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know where a message has been forwarded to. Anyone who can see your or your channels messages can forward them wherever they like to.

---

Edit to Update:

You can use [GetMessagesPublicForwards](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/stats/get-message-public-forwards) to get a list of messages in other public channels that your channel message was forwarded to.

Comment: Do we have a bot which can do the same.?

Answer (score -1):

you can check like this with **pyrogram**

```
from pyrogram improt filters

@app.on_message(filters.channel)
def updates(_, message):
    if message.forward_date:
        print("This message forwarded")
```

pyrorgam [docs](https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/quickstart)